# NodeJS And NowJs server and instant communication

Tags: javascript, node.js, embedded-jetty, nowjs-sockets

I have just come across NodeJS and NowJS and I'm really interested in the technology. What I would like to do is, I would like to build an Facebook instant commenting-like application, where users comment on other's post and instantly appear on the other side. I have just seen the screencast about NowJS and NodeJS and I think that would do the job.

My understanding is you need build some kind of a webserver in NodeJs and use NowJs to listen/receive the message, so webserver.js (implemented in NodeJs) would be the a different webserver than jetty webserver and listen to different ports? And I have to run webserver.js separately.

My Question would be,  If I do something on Jetty like receive some calculation on the browser and when it's finished send the message to webserver.js and it will distribute the message to all listening clients?

Comment: This may not be a stupid question once you figure out what your question is, actually. ;-) Because I couldn't.

Comment: My question would be, I want to call Java library in NodeJs to return some information. Can I do that in NodeJs? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Jetty is working on the client and it's interaction with server is totally separate from Nowjs.

You could let Jetty do all the stuff and then update the Nowjs variable *at the client-side*. Nowjs will itself transfer the change to the server and further to all the rest of connected clients.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but do you have a link to a tutorial or how Jetty is going to corporate with NowJs? Thanks a lot